# react-datetime plugin returning previous selected date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datetime

I am using react-datetime. when select first its returning undefined value if i select date second time its returning date which i selected previous time.Can any one fix this for me. thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
 handleChange(date)
{
console.log("this.state.datetime",$('.rdtOpen>input').val());
this.setState({"customerDOB":date.utc().format('MM/DD/YYYY')})
console.log(date.utc().format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
}
<Datetime dateFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" value ={this.state.datetime} id="datefield"   onChange={this.handleChange} inputProps={{ placeholder: 'MM/DD/YYYY'}} timeFormat={false} />
```

Comment: can u explai more.. u mean ur first console.log gives u old value?

Comment: when i select date first time it returns undefined next time if i select it returns the old value which i selected first time...etc

Comment: ohh.. can u tell me which is returning.. which line are u talking about in handle change? may be add the outputs of console.log to your question.

Comment: this.state.datetime 
AddCustomer.js:54 02/18/2018 Here i selected 19 but its returned 18

Comment: i dn get it.. are u talking about `this .state.datetime` if so.. where are u setting this state? if u r talking about the console.log statement u have written.. u should add the consle.log output..

Comment: console.log(date.utc().format('MM/DD/YYYY'));     02/18/2018(output)

Comment: ha ha.. that might be coz.. the actual time in utc would be a day before.. try to check if ur actal time is that value in utc..